# Parallelism improvement

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

Is there a better pattern for parallelism that can be improved in the following code? With all the new Task features in C# I'm wondering if there is room for improvement. The call to TaskManager.StartNew is a wrapper to the Task.Factory.StartNew with exception handling. It basically creates an array of Tasks, and then calls the WaitAll method. Is this the best way to execute these tasks in parallel?

```
 var queries = new Task[]
        {
            TaskManager.StartNew(() =>
                {
                   ...
                }, context.UserContextContainer.UserContext),
            TaskManager.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    ...
                }, context.UserContextContainer.UserContext),
            TaskManager.StartNew(() =>
                {
                   ...
                }, context.UserContextContainer.UserContext),
            TaskManager.StartNew(() =>
                {
                   ...
                }, context.UserContextContainer.UserContext),
            TaskManager.StartNew(() =>
                {
                   ...
                }, context.UserContextContainer.UserContext)
        };


  Task.WaitAll(queries);
```

Comment: Might be a better fit for CodeReview?  I'll flag for move.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes.

Comment: What is all this work you're doing? Elaborate more please. Is it IO bound? CPU bound? Is there any shared state?

Comment: Most of the tasks are database bound. About two of them, the rest are CPU bound.

Comment: Database calls are IO calls. No need to wrap them with a threadpool thread.

Comment: @Yuval, can you tell me why IO calls don't need to be wrapped with a threadpool thread?

Comment: @Ray Because IO calls are asynchronous by nature. They're implemented asynchronously all the way down to the device driver (for example - network device drivers, disk device drivers). What this means is that the operation will execute async disregarding the thread which is used for execution.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what is running in each task. If those tasks are cpu-bound(heavy computations for example) then you are okay with this code. However if those tasks are I/O bound (like web service call, database call, file operation) then it is better to design this in a async/await way. That way you do not block all the cores you have.

If you have 4 cores and lets say 8 tasks, actually your code does the job 4 by 4. When you rewrite it with async/await pattern all the task will run in parallel. But again you do not need to do this if your tasks are cpu bound.

Comment: what do you mean by the "async/await" way?